# If the derivative map at the identity is bijective, then all derivitive maps are bijective

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, tangent-bundle

I'd like to prove the following statement:

Suppose that $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are Lie groups with corresponding Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_{1}$ and $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$. Suppose that $f : G_{1} \to G_{2}$ is a smooth homomorphism. If $df_{I} : \mathfrak{g}_{1} \to \mathfrak{g}_{2}$ is bijective, then $df_{g} : \mathcal{T}_{g}\left( G_{1} \right) \to \mathcal{T}_{f(g)}\left( G_{2} \right)$ is bijective for all $g \in G_{1}$

This seems to be a commonly-used result in the textbooks I'm reading, but I can't find a proof of it. How do you prove this?

If I take any point $g \in G_{1}$, and a tangent vector $x \in \mathcal{T}_{g}(G_{1})$, then I know that:
$$
df_{g}(x) = (f \circ \gamma)^{\prime}(0)
$$ 
Where $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to G_{1}$ is a curve such that $\gamma(0)=I$ and $\gamma^{\prime}(0) = x$. My thinking is a somehow need to "translate" $\mathfrak{g}_{1}$ to $\mathcal{T}_{g}(G_{1})$....any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the equation $f(gh)=f(g)f(h)$, then this can be written in terms of left translations as $f\circ\lambda_g=\lambda_{f(g)}\circ f$ and thus as $f=\lambda_{f(g)}\circ f\circ\lambda_{g^{-1}}$. Differentiating this equation in the point $g$, you get $df(g)$ written as a composition of $df(e)$ with two maps which are linar isomorphisms since left translations are diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is $\lambda_{g}$? Is it a curve $\mathbb{R} \to G_{1}$? That we differentiate to get into our tangent space?

Comment: It is the left translation by $g\in G_1$, i.e. $\lambda_g:G_1\to G_1$ defined by $\lambda_g(h)=gh$. This is a diffeomorphism (since the inverse is $\lambda_{g^{-1}}$ and thus has invertible derivative in each point.

Comment: Do you mean $\lambda_{g}(h)=hg$?

Comment: No, I mean $\lambda_g(h)=gh$ (it is "left translation by $g$"), but you can also phrase the argument in terms of right translations if you want to.

Comment: Aha, my mistake! I understand. So now we can use $f = \lambda_{f(g)} \circ f \circ \lambda_{g^{-1}}$ to write: $df_{h} = d\left( \lambda_{f(g)} \circ f \circ \lambda_{g^{-1}} \right) |_{h} = ...?$ Is there some kind of chain rule that can be used?

Comment: I've been able to conclude $df_{g} = d\left( \lambda_{f(g)} \right)_{f(I)} \circ df_{I} \circ d\left( \lambda_{g^{-1}} \right)_{g}$. And I think I understand the proof completely now. Thank you!

Comment: Right, this is the chain rule. Btw: $f(I)=I$ for any homomorphism.